# Degeneration of a spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, spectral-sequences

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry” by Daniel Huybrechts. On page 140, he is written that due to some results the spectral sequence
$$E^{p,q}_2=H^p(X\times X,\mathcal{E}xt^q(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X))\Longrightarrow Ext^{p+q}(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X)$$
degenerates and this implies that
$$Ext^i(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \bigoplus_{p+q=i}H^i(X\times X, \mathcal{E}xt^q(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X))$$
Now, my question is that what is the meaning of the degeneration of a spectral sequence and why does it imply this isomorphism here?

Comment: We say that a spectral sequence degenerates on page $r$ if all the differentials on pages $r$ and higher are 0, so the $r$th page is already the limiting $\infty$ page. As for why that implies the result, well it appears that the claim is the SS degenerates on the $E_2$ page. But that's insufficient for the result in general. You also need to know that there are no extension problems in general. That's going to require an argument specific to the objects involved here.

Comment: Do you know how this spectral sequence shows up? Or do you want an explanation of why the Ext group decomposes as a direct sum?

Comment: @CraniumClamp I want an explanation of why the Ext group decomposes as a direct sum.

Comment: @PouyaLayeghi that is just linear algebra then, if you have understood what it means for the spectral sequence to degenerate.  The $ E_{\infty} $ page has terms which are the filtered pieces of the Ext groups.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Can you elaborate a bit more? How does the filtration of the Ext implies the direct sum decomposition?